# Turn HTML content of a URL into a String

Tags: java, json, android-studio

I have a url:

```
https://blablabla.eu/admin/autolog?format=json
```

and the fact is that I want to turn the content of the url, the html content into a String variable in order to transform the string into a JSON file.

I tried to transform the url into a string, but that's not like that x)

Edit:

Log.i("Apple", "" + url);

if (url.startsWith("https://intra.epitech.eu/admin/autolog?format=json"))
{

try {
    Log.i("Chcolate", "YES");

```
    URL true_url = new URL(url);
    Log.i("LAMA", "YES");
    String html = true_url.getContent().toString();
    Log.i("SUPERLAMA", "YES" + 
    Log.i("STRAWBERRY", "" + html);
    autologin_token = return_token(html);
```

}}

There is the code I have so far, the log are here to check where I can go.

Comment: Where is the HTML content?

Comment: Hum, the url is in String url, but that's what I want to know, how to have the html content of the url.

Comment: Can you provide some context for example the code that you have tried?

Comment: JSON follows a specific format which is nothing like an HTML page, unless the data you want to fetch has an API created using which you can request for a certain format but other than that it is only possible to get the contents from the url and store it in a json format that you create yourself.

Comment: the ``format=json`` at the end suggests that the output will be json, there won't be any html involved here.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com");
String content = url.getContent().toString();
```

I'm not sure whether you get the HTML content but just give it a try.

(I would love to answer in comment section but i don't have access, yet...)

Comment: Ok, so with my test
this is ok: `URL true_url = new URL(url);`

but not this:
`String html = true_url.getContent().toString();`

Comment: @Folamie what do you mean? What exactly is not "ok"?

Comment: Well, I can create the URL, but I can't get the content :/